# From development (app_dev.php) to production (app.php) in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, production-environment, assetic, symfony-2.4

I'm working in a Symfony2 project, under development enviroment `app_dev.php` all works fine but when I go to production `app.php` I get this error at Firebug console:

> "NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://applicationtest.com/css/fmain.css"

And of course CSS and JS isn't working, what I miss?

Comment: RTFM: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/deployment-tools.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you have not dumped `assetic` resources:

```
php app/console assetic:dump --env=prod
```

And then try again...

Answer (score 0):

for example:

```
//routing.yml
test_root: 
    path: /css/fmain.css
    defaults:  { _controller: AcmeBlogBundle:Blog:index }
..
```

is valid.
That means that the request of that root will call the indexAction of the Blog Controller in my exemple.

thought, are you trying just to include some css file?

is so check the doc: http://symfony.com/fr/doc/current/book/templating.html#liens-vers-des-fichiers